# Unity doesn't show some running apps

Tags: unity, 13.04

In ubuntu 13.04, after a fresh install. Unity does not show some running apps in the unity bar or when alternating app with alt+tab. when upgraded from 12.10 this did not happen.

Example apps: terminal, repository-software-manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That has happened to me, too. What I did about it was unpinned chrome (though, it may be a different app causing this problem for you), then pinned the terminal, and that fixed all of the other apps for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Both answers worked, but the unpin+pin only worked with some apps. note that this in the upgraded version from 12.10 did not happen. hope there is an update soon.

Comment: I would like to clarify, this has never happened to me in 13.04, but in a previous installation of 12.10, I have encountered this bug.

Comment: don’t know what app I unpinned but it fixed the problem. removed almost every thing...

Answer (score 1):

Temporary workaround might be to use Meta + w to get to all open apps.

Comment: This was the only way to switch to [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en). [This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/951929) was the closest related bug I found on Launchpad.